# How do I set my global account to email me of replies?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, email

I'd like to set my account to email me if someone responds to, comments on, or edits, my question or answer, or a question I've answered, similar to a forum or wiki notification system.

I don't care about receiving 1k+ emails every minute; I just want to be notified at the moment the event happens.

How do I set my global account to notify me about any action on my posts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your profile navigate to Settings -> Preferences -> Edit Email Settings and there is a setting to email you unread inbox messages that can be done every 3 hours, every 6 hours or daily. You also can set what address it is sent to in the same area.

Also if you keep a page open the notification bar will update in real time

Comment: What about instantly rather than a static time?

Comment: There is no "instant" option for email, @Tcll; if you want instant notifications, keep a site open and logged in, and the top bar indicator will light up in real-time.

Comment: Can I make this a request, because I'd like instant emails, not instant site notifications. And no this browser does not do real-time.

Comment: @Tcll They don't have an option to send the notifications instantly for a reason. Mainly as that would put a lot more load on their system if they had to sent out an email every time someone got a notification.

Comment: That's kind of an invalid argument, because of the app and site notifications... I don't see why email can't join the mix... >.>

Comment: @Tcll The app and site notifications get the updates via an API, sending an actual email for each update is a different matter and will put more load on their processing power and network bandwith.

Comment: So make the system more efficient and modernize it... I realize the system has more people than major forums and wikis, but doesn't facebook do it as well?

Comment: Proboards does it, your argument is invalid. I guess I can compromise at a lacking system which needs a major update... so I'll accept this answer, but I hope to see this in the future.

Comment: @Tcll Other people doing something doesn't mean it is the correct or best way to be doing something.

Comment: There is  no "correct" way, but it is the preferred and modern way. Thus you guys complaining about load and bandwidth just means your system needs to be stronger to match modern systems. (something which takes time to achieve)

Comment: @Tcll fyi, I am a normal user and have no affiliation with stack overflow, I am just pointing out the concerns that I would see if I was to implement a similar system. Also need to consider the fact that this question would have sent me 7 emails so far which raises the possibility that email servers would mark stack overflow as a spammer when they have to send out a lot of emails to every user.

Comment: Alright, excuse me for thinking otherwise. But do consider that computers and networking have evolved making real-time data anything but a big deal. (I'm not experienced with networking, though am starting  to pick up on it for my programs, which will end up with a larger bandwidth than modded minecraft)

Comment: A spam site, please, I get more emails from MinecraftForum than this site would've output with the allotted time.

Comment: Btw just to note, it's common sense to filter the email alerts and allow disabling notifications of comments or edits... so to the devs, be smart with my request ;)